# How to add white space in the comment in Doxygen

Tags: whitespace, doxygen

I was wondering is there any way to insert white space in the comment in html of Doxygen? I searched online and Doxygen manual, but I couldn't find anything to do that.

For example, I am trying to add comment as following:

```
//!   motor_id,          motor direction,   accel,     min veloc,     max veloc\n
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_1,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360\n
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_2,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360\n
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_3,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360\n
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_4,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360\n
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_5,     CLOCKWISE,         400,       200,           350\n
```

But the html output shows the result like this

```
motor_id, motor direction, accel, min veloc, max veloc
GAUGE_MOTOR_1, CLOCKWISE, 100, 1, 360
GAUGE_MOTOR_2, CLOCKWISE, 100, 1, 360
GAUGE_MOTOR_3, CLOCKWISE, 100, 1, 360
GAUGE_MOTOR_4, CLOCKWISE, 100, 1, 360
GAUGE_MOTOR_5, CLOCKWISE, 400, 200, 350
```

The white space between two words will be shrinked to one space by doxygen automatically. Is there anybody know how to fix this? That will help a lot.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use either

```
//! <pre>
//!   motor_id,          motor direction,   accel,     min veloc,     max veloc
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_1,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_2,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_3,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_4,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_5,     CLOCKWISE,         400,       200,           350
//! </pre>
```

or

```
//! \verbatim
//!   motor_id,          motor direction,   accel,     min veloc,     max veloc
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_1,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_2,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_3,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_4,     CLOCKWISE,         100,       1,             360
//!   GAUGE_MOTOR_5,     CLOCKWISE,         400,       200,           350
//! \endverbatim
```

The latter will really show the text as-is. 
The former will still let doxygen interpret commands inside the block, while preserving spaces.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I find it useful to use an HTML table, and put the content in a separate file.  For instance, you could create a file named "motors.html", put it in a place where your doxygen is configured to find input files, and then use the following command to include motors.html into your source code:

```
@htmlinclude motors.html
```

In motors.html, you could have something along the following lines:

```
<center> 
<table border="0"> 
<tr> 
  <th>motor_id</th> 
  <th>motor direction</th> 
  <th>accel</th> 
  <th>min veloc</th> 
  <th>max veloc</th> 
<tr> 
<tr> 
  <td>GAUGE_MOTOR_1</td> 
  <td>CLOCKWISE</td> 
  <td>100</td> 
  <td>1</td> 
  <td>360</td> 
</tr> 
... 
</table> 
</center>
```

You can use a CSS file to style the table.